# iBeacon notification database

Tags: ios, notifications, uuid, ibeacon

I have a question which I have not been able to figure out so I decided to see if I can get some help on here.

I am working on an iBeacons project and I  have been able to understand the basic function of iBeacons, setting up UUID'S and major and minor id's to specify exact notifications, but my question is how do I dynamically update information I send out to the users without having to go into the code each time to do this. Do I need to create a database to store all my information I want to push out to users? if so how will this database constantly refresh messages pushed out to users?  An example would be lets say if you walk into a store and you get a notification in the shoe section saying there is a 10 percent off, you look at the notification but not too impressed and start to walk out, then you get another notification saying for today only you can get a 25 percent off... The app has to dynamically refresh for this to be possible.

Please help me clarify this

Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is to store this deal information in a web service so you can update it without changing the app.  Your app would need to download the updated deal information from the web service either when it starts up or when it sees an iBeacon.

My company, Radius Networks, offers a tool called [Proximity Kit](http://www.proximitykit.com) that makes this easy.  You can assign arbitrary key/value pairs to iBeacons using a web interface.  Then your app downloads them automatically an has access to them whenever you see iBeacons.

In your scenario, they key/values could be something like:

> primary_offer_text=10% off all shoes
>
> secondary_offer_text=20% off all shoes